# access convert string like "FEB 2017" to date

Tags: vba, ms-access

report out of account system comes out with month like "FEB 2017". I need to convert that string to a date that is the end of the month like 02/28/2017. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT LastDayInMonth(DateValue(Mid("Feb 2017", 1, 3) & " 1, " &
                                Mid("Feb 2017", 5, 4))) AS LastDayInMonth
FROM yourTable
```

**Explanation:**

The concatenated term inside the call to `DateValue()` will be `Feb 1, 2017`, and will evaluate to the same date, at least for the sample data I used.  In general, it will be the first day of the month for the data you showed us.  Then, we use `LastDayInMonth()` to shift that date to the last day of the same month.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use native functions, adding one month, subtracting one day:

```
MonthYear = "FEB 2017"
Ultimo = DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("m", 1, CDate("1 " & MonthYear)))

Ultimo -> 2017-02-28
```